# xcode 4 - custom keyboard with two Text Fields

Tags: iphone, xcode, keyboard, xcode4.2, textfield

I have created a custom keyboard and I have two text fields. When the user clicks on one of them, the keyboard appears.

How can I know which text field is currently active so that I write what the user is typing from the keyboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would do:

Tag both textfields (or use properties)

```
textField1.tag = 100;
textField2.tag = 101;
```

Also set their delegates.

```
textField1.delegate = self;
textField2.delegate = self;
```

On the .h file declare your class will implement the UITextFieldDelegate Protocol

and on the .m

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField.tag == 100) //you should use a constant instead of 100
    {
        //set a breakpoint here so you would know your typing the first textField
        return YES;
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by : On the .h file declare your class will implement the UITextFieldDelegate Protocol

Comment: @interface YourViewController : UIViewController  <UITextFieldDelegate>